# USB Audio Buffer Underrun

Tags: c, audio, usb, microcontroller, race-condition

I'm working on a USB Audio aysnchronous implementation on a microcontroller and I seem to be running into buffer underrun issues on the input side of things at 48kHz sample rate/24 bit rate (it works at 44.1kHz though).

I'm double buffering in my implementation:

(1) Codec -> DMA has a couple buffers. When one buffer is completely filled, I load this into my USB buffers.

(2) USB side has 40 buffers (basically 40ms of data). When a buffer's status is "FILLED", it is okay to send. A USB callback is done after a successful USB transfer and sends the next filled buffer.

In my implementation, I fill at least 3/4 of the buffers (30 buffers) before before USB starts transferring actual data (so in the first 30ms, it's just "silent" data). Basically, the buffer underrun happens as my codec/dma buffer is not completely filled yet and the next buffer to be read is "EMPTY". I feel like the easiest solution to this would be to have more buffers (clearly 40 buffers is not enough; approximately 11kb of data since 40 * 294 bytes = 11760 bytes), however I cannot increase it as my microcontroller has simply run out of available memory.

What are my options to solving this at this point of time? Is there a workaround to the limit of available buffers I have/available leftover memory? Or is the only way to add a SRAM on to have enough available buffers.

Thanks!

**EDIT**: It appears this is a bit confusing. Basically codec isn't filling fast enough; thus, there are gaps of data in USB buffers and creating an "underrun" of data.

**EDIT2**: I'm running an asynchronous with implicit sync endpoint; host is being read once per frame. Sorry that wasn't clear either.

Comment: If I understand this correctly then you can't fill the send buffers fast enough, right? In this case you have to either use more memory and fill the buffers in advance or you have to make the code which fills these buffers faster...

Comment: @SisterFister Yea that's basically it. I guess I will add this as an edit in my question to make it clearer. OK that's what I was afraid of. I'll have to think about this more. Thanks!

Comment: Ok... What platform are you using and why does it take so long to fill these buffers?

Comment: @SisterFister I'm using a Cortex-M3. As for why it's taking so long... I'm not sure. At 44.1kHz it fills fast enough (fills 88 samples per call). I'm assuming my codec/dma is just filling up too slowly when I switch to 48kHz (fills 96 samples per call). At this point I'm not sure how to make my codec/dma buffer filling shorter (done via interrupts).

Comment: I'm also working with the Cortex-M3 (ATSAM3X8E)... What codec are you using and where does the data come from? Have you looked at the assembler output already? Sometimes GCC generates really strange code...

Comment: @SisterFister oh interesting! I'm using a 32 bit codec and I'm clocking it at the appropriate sample frequency clocks (11.2896MHz for 44.1, 12.288MHz for 48). I have actually not looked at the assembler output; how would looking at that help me out? Not too familiar with assembly

Comment: To get the assembler code call `gcc` with the `-S` flag. But I still don't really know where the data comes from and where it goes...

Comment: @SisterFister Codec -> SSC -> DMAC -> DMAC interrupt -> USB buffers; USB is running on its own; USB input starts; USB sends next filled buffer; USB callback upon successful transfer; repeats USB send

Comment: I don't fully understand it either.  If the USB is getting rid of buffers faster than the Codec can fill them, is that not a good thing?

Comment: @MartinJames Codec isn't filling fast enough. USB has an empty buffer when codec isn't filled yet

Comment: You are reading the data from [I2S](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2S) or a codec and then sending it to a USB device? If this is the case, could you post your code which copies the data between these buffers?

Comment: @yun.cloud I get that, I think.  All your USB buffers are empty, codec has not yet filled a buffer.  Is that correct, because that doesn't sound at all bad?  Just stop sending USB stuff until the codec fills a buffer?

Comment: @MartinJames I think he wants to continuously send USB packets, so he always has to keep some buffers filled.

Comment: @SisterFister well, that's a problem because the incoming data rate is fixed by the codec/sampling, so data will always either underflow or overflow depending on USB link speed.  The intervals for USB buffer send could, I suppose, be spread out so that the USB data flow is less ummm.. blocky, but I'm still not sure what the OP wants to do.  At least it's not overrun;)

Comment: @MartinJames That's exactly the issue. I guess I did not explain it very well. I found myself having more issues when the USB packets weren't continuously being sent. How would I got with overcoming the underflow issue? At 44.1kHz I do not encounter this issue since there's enough buffering to prevent the underflow/overflow issue

Comment: @SisterFister I am using I2S. I will post code in a bit

Comment: This may sound a bit odd, but try reducing the number of USB buffers, maybe even down to one.  The USB is eating buffers faster than they can be filled, so there is no actual need for a USB buffer queue?

Comment: @MartinJames Multiple buffers are used to be able to fill one buffer while another one is being sent...

Comment: You likely need the feedback mechanism that throttles the consumption of your data by the host.  See  https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/white-papers/usb-audio-simplified.pdf as a bit of an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your endpoint should be read by host once per frame (I assume you are constructing isochronous IN endpoint, async with implicit synchronization). If this is not true in your case, please state it clearly in your question as it would be quite strange problem.

Anyway, because of that, there is not much use for more than three buffers (two will do with bit of careful thinking too). You do not need more buffers. But your buffers should be somewhat longer than calculated nominal samples-per-frame and your endpoint's descriptor should contain this extended length.

Then, you *always* switch buffer being filled on and only on the start of USB frame (or on any other event synchronized with USB SOF). *Regardless of the amount of data in the current buffer!* When USB host wants to read from your endpoint, your device has to return as many samples as there actually is in the currently read buffer. No more, no less.

So there is no chance for underrun. You simply send lesser number of samples to the host when the buffer being read was not fully filled before and it is host's task to deal with clock drift and resampling in whichever suitable way. You *could* worry about overrun on the other hand. If SOF frequency would be too low compared to ADC's sample rate, you could fill whole buffer before SOF comes and end up with no place for next sample. Simple fix is to make your buffer is at least few samples longer than calculated nominal rate. You should be safe then, otherwise things are probably already broken much more elsewhere.

Last problem you could worry about is host not sending read request for your endpoint while SOFs are ticking normally. Well, in this case overwriting old buffers can not hurt much as host is obviously not interested in data in this very moment and buffering things -- thus increasing latency -- will likely do more bad than good.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I'm going to think about what you said and try to apply it. Will post more details soon